# How to see XML coding of SVG image created in Inkscape?

Tags: images, html, xml, svg

I heard that SVG files are made of XML and HTML but softwares like Inkscape are used to create SVG images easily without worrying about coding in XML.

Hence after creating a SVG image I want to view a XML coding of it because I can change the colors and size dynamically through programming I believe off course am not sure about this.

After creating a SVG image I can only able to see a file not a coding in DOM also (viewed in Firebug).

Here is my question is that possible to view and edit a XML coding of SVG image after creating it in Inkscape?

Comment: Any kind of text editor will do. Just open it with Vim, Emacs, Geany, VS Codium, VS Code, Notepad++...

Answer (score 11):

Inkscape has a built-in XML editor:

1. Click **Edit > XML Editor** (or press <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+x</kbd>).

The XML source appears.

Comment: That helps ... unless you're trying to copy portions (e.g. to convert it into a stencil / diagram / object for a related program like Pencil), so other tools are useful too.

Answer (score 1):

xml code for SVG images can be seen in IDE,there are sites which provide a tool to give us a xml of code of SVG image we created, by this you can play around with the style of the images in code.

Once if you put a xml format of SVG image then you can see it on DOM too(seen in firebug), but if you put just image alone not a coding then you can't able to see coding, this is what i experienced before posting this question.

So, finally yes you can see the xml format of svg images which are created in Vector Graphic Software and change its color,dimensions,etc. in xml format.

hope this will help others:)

Answer (score 1):

- **Geany** on *Linux* OS's works great.
- I would imagine that **Notepad++** (what I used before Geany) on *Windows* OS's would work well also.